Change the background view of UITableViewCell when dragging during reorder
When the user is reordering their items and dragging on a cell, I want the cell to have a thin material as background. However, when the user isn't dragging any cells, the background would be clear to allow the table view background view to come through the cells.
I am unable to get this to work...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragPreviewParametersForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIDragPreviewParameters? {
        // Create a copy of the cell for drag preview
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return nil }
        
        // Create a visual effect view with blur effect
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterial))
        blurEffectView.frame = cell.bounds
        
        // Create a preview parameters object
        let previewParameters = UIDragPreviewParameters()
        let previewView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
        previewView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        previewParameters.visiblePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: previewView.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)
        previewParameters.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        return previewParameters
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        let item = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
            ItemRow(item: item)
        }
        return cell
    }


have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/3751735-configurationupdatehandler

In short: You have to create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell. Override layoutSubviews to attach a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to UITableViewCellReorderControl. Define a protocol and use a delegate to inform whoever you want to about the dragging state.
CustomTableViewCell.swift:
import UIKit

// Define the protocol in Swift
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func customTableViewCell(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell, isDragging value: Bool)
}

// Create the custom table view cell
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Declare the delegate property
    weak var delegate: CustomTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in subviews {
            if NSStringFromClass(type(of: subview)).contains("ReorderControl") {
                if subview.gestureRecognizers?.isEmpty ?? true {
                    let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
                    gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
                    gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.150
                    subview.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func handleGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            delegate?.customTableViewCell(self, isDragging: true) // Dragging started
        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            delegate?.customTableViewCell(self, isDragging: false) // Dragging ended
        }
    }
}

ViewController.swift:
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CustomTableViewCellDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10 // Example row count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func customTableViewCell(_ cell: CustomTableViewCell, isDragging value: Bool) {
        // Handle the delegate callback, change color when cell is being dragged
        print("Cell is dragging: \(value)")
    }
}

